# How do I delete custom events from the dashboard on Branch.io?

Tags: android, branch.io

I have events that are not being tracked anymore. How can I remove them from my Branch dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amruta from [branch.io](http://branch.io/) here:

Analytics software rarely allows you to directly modify historical data, so there is no way to completely DELETE custom events created from the Branch dashboard. This could lead to corrupted or inaccurate data.

However, if a particular custom event has not occurred within the particular time frame you are viewing, it should not show on the Branch dashboard. Say you have a custom event 'signup'. If you select 'Last 7 days' time frame and the 'signup' event has occurred 0 number of times it will not be shown in the drop-down.
If the 'signup' event has not occurred even once for the 'Last 90 days' it will automatically stop showing on the dashboard.